# The parameter is incorrect - SAML 2.0 - Custom Policy in AzureAD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, nemlogin

I'm in the process of setting up a SAML 2.0 service provider on B2C using custom policies.

With my current setup i can login on the IDP, and get redirected to my B2C assertionconsumer link where i am greeted with the following message:
`AADB2C: An exception has occurred.`

I discovered that the SAML response returned to B2C had a success status code by using SAML-tracer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="_bbe4821c-dcc6-e7be-685c-2a655f2bd93e" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2021-06-29T07:08:50.8079797Z" Destination="https://myb2ctenant.b2clogin.com/myb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase/samlp/sso/assertionconsumer" InResponseTo="_9c51291e-0838-4d76-b87b-06378b62a2e0">
   <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">https://saml.test-devtest4-nemlog-in.dk</Issuer>
   <Status>
      <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
   </Status>
   <EncryptedAssertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
      <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
         <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#aes256-gcm" />
         <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <xenc:EncryptedKey>
               <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#rsa-oaep">
                  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                  <xenc11:MGF xmlns:xenc11="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#mgf1sha256" />
               </xenc:EncryptionMethod>
               <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                  <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                     <X509Data>
                        <X509IssuerSerial>
                           <X509IssuerName>CN=TRUST2408 Systemtest XXXIV CA, O=TRUST2408, C=DK</X509IssuerName>
                           <X509SerialNumber>1604005554</X509SerialNumber>
                        </X509IssuerSerial>
                     </X509Data>
                  </o:SecurityTokenReference>
               </KeyInfo>
               <xenc:CipherData>
                  <xenc:CipherValue>ZgKyS3kIO8466MCUN2fts1lKowwmipX7V5mKtyFNl7trDKeTJ/liKGB0nv33/aMrELWTvlD/EybYN7stD57hlzste1qgHQALAVnsGnCd5eWulPIQVfNPhAvz8eoEviNMv6wYxc7FqMUnZ2js4ZvyGMMZIm0pZya49qIzBmT+fo+cFQ335aLIKzJvZAMQMQiMcjKL4dmR5sRorIBNoSoVggiTVI0BcegUZxf8MFgCj0GE2EucgfvjW+7UDh3PkEQt2piyvIMi/GJFrf57O0LkEFioq2xXBP16I18jhVrjZe6ZTRG+s2d/wDN+0mLdh/8X+Vh6bhoIMorXCjtk7p4yxQ==</xenc:CipherValue>
               </xenc:CipherData>
            </xenc:EncryptedKey>
         </ds:KeyInfo>
         <xenc:CipherData>
            <xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue>
         </xenc:CipherData>
      </xenc:EncryptedData>
   </EncryptedAssertion>
</Response>
```

I setup Application Insights for the relying party using [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights) and managed to get the following error:

```
{
    ""Kind"": ""Headers"",
    ""Content"": {
      ""UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint"": ""urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights"",
      ""CorrelationId"": ""d50ab845-8e9c-4958-8f0d-9b918ac3d651"",
      ""EventInstance"": ""Event:ClaimsExchange"",
      ""TenantId"": ""mytenant.onmicrosoft.com"",
      ""PolicyId"": ""B2C_1A_nemlogin3""
    }
  },
  {
    ""Kind"": ""Transition"",
    ""Content"": {
      ""EventName"": ""ClaimsExchange"",
      ""StateName"": ""Initial""
    }
  },
  {
    ""Kind"": ""Predicate"",
    ""Content"": ""Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.ClaimsExchangeMessageValidationHandler""
  },
  {
    ""Kind"": ""FatalException"",
    ""Content"": {
      ""Time"": ""9:40 AM"",
      ""Exception"": {
        ""Kind"": ""Handled"",
        ""HResult"": ""80090027"",
        ""Message"": ""The parameter is incorrect.\r\n"",
        ""Data"": {}
      }
    }
  }
```

I have been trying to troubleshoot the error: `""Message"": ""The parameter is incorrect.\r\n""`

[link to idp metadata](https://www.nemlog-in.dk/media/zrrb0a1e/oio_saml_3_test-devtest4-idp-metadata-xml.txt)

My technical profile below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TechnicalProfile Id="NemLogin-SAML3">
   <DisplayName>NemLogin3</DisplayName>
   <Description>Login with your NemLogin3 account</Description>
   <Protocol Name="SAML2" />
   <Metadata>
      <Item Key="IssuerUri">myIssuerId</Item>
      <Item Key="PartnerEntity">https://www.nemlog-in.dk/media/zrrb0a1e/oio_saml_3_test-devtest4-idp-metadata-xml.txt</Item>
      <Item Key="NameIdPolicyFormat">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</Item>
      <Item Key="ResponsesSigned">false</Item>
      <Item Key="WantsEncryptedAssertions">true</Item>
   </Metadata>
   <CryptographicKeys>
      <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_Test" />
      <Key Id="SamlAssertionDecryption" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_Test" />
   </CryptographicKeys>
   <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="assertionSubjectName" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="specVersion" Required="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="loa" Required="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="cvr" Required="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="orgName" Required="true" />
   </OutputClaims>
   <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Saml-idp" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Can you include the full SAML response?

Comment: @DanielKrasnove I have added the full response to the question now.

Comment: Can you try the following incrementally:
1. Instead of the URL, paste the content of your SAML metadata as CDATA.
2. Remove the NameIdPolicyFormat metadata item.
3. Disable all signing and encryption (Make sure to adjust this on the IdP side as well)

Comment: @DanielKrasnove I tried your 2 first suggestions, however my idp does not probide the possiblity to disable signing and encryption.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to utilize a free service like Auth0 to create a SAML IdP and try to at least get a working sample. Then you can incrementally make changes to duplicate your real IdP's config until you able to potentially reproduce the error.